# Footer will not go to the very bottom of the browser page

Tags: html, css

I have inserted the footer but when I open the preview of the web page the footer is at the bottom, but once I scroll down it is stuck to one position in the page. 
I don't want it to be fixed or sticky, just want it to viewed once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

Here is the footer div tag in my html

```
<div id="footer">
 FOOTER
</div>
```

and the css for this footer is as follows

```
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cewo3h2/

I don't know whether I have a problem with other positions on the page causing the footer to stay in one position and not move to the very bottom of the page, but any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post more code from the page? Or a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5cewo3h2/

Comment: I want the footer to show under the three circle buttons

Comment: @Cobby Perhaps I misunderstood you. In your demo, I see FOOTER underneath the three circle buttons, and it's only visible when I scroll all the way down. Isn't that the behavior you were looking for?

Comment: When its opened in the browser and if you widen the window in the demo the footer is actually just above the circle buttons and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

Comment: @Cobby Ah I see. Michael's answer will help you- just nest the footer div into the bottom "grid_3" element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the footer element into the grid.

Move:

```
<div id="footer">
    FOOTER
</div>
```

to a spot in between the last two divs in the HTML:

```
    </div>

 <div id="footer">
    FOOTER
   </div>

</div>

    </center>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/5cewo3h2/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, it is always something so simple but a fresh set of eyes always fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of absolute positioning. Just put the div at the bottom (under your content divs) and it'll render under them.

```
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```